# Permutation of Combination. How do I work out this example?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have this question which is raising how I can differentiate permutation from combination.

I have the word BOOMBASTIC.

a) Find the number of different selections of 3 letters that can be formed from the letters of the word.

b) Of the above selection, how many contain at least one vowel?

for a) at first thought, I thougt this is a simple permutation of $\dfrac{n!}{n-k}!$ hence $ \dfrac{10!}{(10-3)!}$

at second thought, since there are repetitions, I am thinking it should be $ \dfrac{10!}{2!2!}$ because of the repeated Bs and Os.

But again, the wordings talk of a "selection", which I read that it is one of the catch words to look for in Combinations. So this one comes to me as $ 10C3 = \dfrac{10!}{(10-3)!3!} = \dfrac{10!}{7!3!}$

Answer (score 0):

The repetitions complicate matters, but only slightly. Note that there are $8$ distinct letters. Hence, there are ${}_8C_3$ selections of $3$ letters without repeats. There are also $7$ selections of $3$ with repeated $B$s and $7$ selections of $3$ with repeated $O$s.

For the second one, I recommend counting the ones *without* vowels, and subtracting them from the total.

**P.S.**: The actual word is "bombastic." If that's what the word is actually supposed to be, then you'll need to adapt the answer above just a bit.

Comment: But your logic precludes counting the distinct word "BOB", or "OBB", or "BBO", or "BOO", or ...

Comment: Does it? I think that $2$ $B$s and $1$ $O$ is counted among the $7$ selections of $3$ with repeated $B$s. Likewise, $2$ $O$s and $1$ $B$ should be taken care of.